# How to automate making points in a powerpoint presentation appear on click for the entire presentation 

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I already know how to make each bullet point on a PowerPoint slide appear on click:

```
1. Select all the bullet points
2. Click "Add Animation"
3. Select "Appear"
4. Select Start = "On Click"
```

This reveals each point on a slide one by one as I click.

My question is, is there a way to do this for all points in the whole presentation in one go, rather than having to go through this process on every slide individually?

(I'm using PowerPoint 2010)

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really automate it per se but makes the work easier.

Try to apply the animation you want for the bullet points in the Slide Master then you can apply that animation to any slide with the same Slide Layout of the Slide Master.

Here's how:

1. Switch to the Slide Master view by clicking on **View** Tab → **Slide Master**.

   [image]
2. Select the **Title and Content** Slide Layout which would be **third slide** thumbnail in the Slides tab.

   [image]
3. Select the bullet points in the slide and apply the animation you want and select "On Click" on Start. Close the Master Slide.

   [image]
4. Now, back to your presentation, click on the placeholder on the slide with the bullet points and on the Animation Pane, you should already see an animation that has a label of "Layout: Body". All you have to do is click on it's arrow and select "Copy Effects to Slide".

   [image]
5. All animations you applied on the Master Slide of the same layout, will be applied to the slide.

   [image]
6. Every time you want to apply the animation to bullet points, you just select the placeholder that contains the bullets and select "Copy Effects to Slide" from the Animation Pane.

Comment: thanks this looks like a step in the right direction. I'll try that out next time I do a presentation